# what's the diffrence bettwen go/token and token in go/src/cmd/compile/internal/syntax

Tags: go

They are very similar.And there's more: scanner,parser.Why are they similar but difference.

go/scanner like this:

```
func (s *Scanner) Scan() (pos token.Pos, tok token.Token, lit string) {
scanAgain:
    s.skipWhitespace()

    // current token start
    pos = s.file.Pos(s.offset)

    // determine token value
    insertSemi := false
    switch ch := s.ch; {
    case isLetter(ch):
        lit = s.scanIdentifier()
        if len(lit) > 1 {
            // keywords are longer than one letter - avoid lookup otherwise
            tok = token.Lookup(lit)
            switch tok {
            case token.IDENT, token.BREAK, token.CONTINUE, token.FALLTHROUGH, token.RETURN:
                insertSemi = true
            }
        }
```

scanner in cmd like this:

```
func (s *scanner) next() {
    nlsemi := s.nlsemi
    s.nlsemi = false

redo:
    // skip white space
    s.stop()
    startLine, startCol := s.pos()
    for s.ch == ' ' || s.ch == '\t' || s.ch == '\n' && !nlsemi || s.ch == '\r' {
        s.nextch()
    }

    // token start
    s.line, s.col = s.pos()
    s.blank = s.line > startLine || startCol == colbase
    s.start()
    if isLetter(s.ch) || s.ch >= utf8.RuneSelf && s.atIdentChar(true) {
        s.nextch()
        s.ident()
        return
    }
```

I think they sould be same,what's the point of this?

Comment: `go/token` is part of the (public) standard library. This can't be changed in a backward-incompatible way. `go/src/cmd/compile/internal/syntax` is an internal package, you can't refer to it. The Go authors are free to change it however they like without affecting anybody else except the compiler implementation. The authors certainly want "freedom" to implement the compiler the way they see fit or be efficient, they don't want the restriction of public packages. Even if this means some code duplication.